# Is there a simple way to have a hierarchical menu in dotnet MAUI?

Tags: xaml, maui

Is there a way to have a traditional hierarchical menu in dotnet MAUI, so when the user clicks on one menu item a submenu appears, or should I completely rethink the navigation? Note that the application is really just for Windows and Mac, though it might be usable on tablets - certainly not phones. The XAML I have tried (with dummy backing methods in the code behind) is:

```
<ShellContent
    Title="Arguments"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ArgumentsPage}"
    Route="ArgumentsPage" />
<ShellContent
    Title="Architecture"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ArchitecturePage}"
    Route="ArchitecturePage"/>
<MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="File">
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New" Clicked="OnFileNewClicked"/>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open" Clicked="OnFileOpenClicked"/>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save" Clicked="OnFileSaveClicked" />
</MenuFlyoutSubItem>
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Module" />
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Settings" />
```

The top level menu items appear, but when I click "File" I don't get the "New", "Open" and "Save".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code to your .xaml:

```xml
<!-- in AppShell.xaml -->
<Shell.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="File">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New" Clicked="OnFileNewClicked"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open" Clicked="OnFileOpenClicked"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save" Clicked="OnFileSaveClicked" />
        </MenuBarItem>
        <MenuBarItem Text="Module" />
        <MenuBarItem Text="Settings" />
</Shell.MenuBarItems>

<!-- or in Page.xaml -->
<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="File">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New" Clicked="OnFileNewClicked"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open" Clicked="OnFileOpenClicked"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save" Clicked="OnFileSaveClicked" />
        </MenuBarItem>
        <MenuBarItem Text="Module" />
        <MenuBarItem Text="Settings" />
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

Remember not to add `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"`. This is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kysFL.jpg).

Comment: Great, thanks. It doesn't put them where I wanted them, but I guess that's part of Shell being "opinionated" - and it is, after all, where Windows and Mac users would expect them, so it does have a point!