# Creating a Menu with Multiple Menu Items when a button is click in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am new to MAUI, transitioning from WPF, and currently exploring the process of displaying a menu with multiple menu items upon clicking a button. Is there a method or approach in MAUI that allows me to achieve this functionality? I know there is `FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout` which only be trigger by right click. I am basically trying to do the same thing but with left click.

Comment: Maybe a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup).

Answer (score 0):

> I am basically trying to do the same thing but with left click.

Unfortunately it can achieve that effect. I see the source code about Context menu: [Context menu support for Windows and MacCatalyst](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/9174), but failed to find a way to modify right-click to left-click.

If you're not limited to Button, [menu bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar) can achieve right-click and left-click simultaneously... And here is my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75872786/19902734).

Or use [PopUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) like ToolmakerSteve said. Here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/Ya0uOaV).